# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString removes whole string

Tags: swift, nsstring

I'm trying to write a string to a text box, but I don't want to write the string if the first character is * or the string == "" but I want to remove all of the spaces to do this

```
for command in InitialCommandsArr {
    let nulledCommand = command.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")

    if nulledCommand != "" && 
       command.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "").characters.first != "*"
    {
        OutputCommand.text = "\(OutputCommand.text),{id:\"MinecartCommandBlock\",Command:\(command)}}"
    }
}
```

When I did this though it replaces the whole string with "" help?

Comment: show sample input and output. what debugging did you do?

Comment: Your code is super confusing. If `InitialCommandsArr` is a variable it should begin with a lower case letter. Same for `OutputCommand`. Also, what is it you're trying to do? Also, it looks like `OutputCommand` is a label or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this:

```
    var labelText = "";
    let initialCommandsArr = ["foo","bar","*baz","   "]

    for command in initialCommandsArr {
        let nulledCommand = command.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        if(nulledCommand.characters.count > 0 && nulledCommand.characters.first != "*"){

            labelText += ",{id:\"MinecartCommandBlock\",Command: \(command) }}"
        }
    }

    print(labelText)
```

Which prints out:

```
,{id:"MinecartCommandBlock",Command: foo }},{id:"MinecartCommandBlock",Command: bar }}
```

That what you want??